# How do you correctly exit a remote job in a PowerShell session

Tags: powershell, rpc, invoke-command

I have a number of remote jobs started with a Powerhsell `invoke-command -session` command. In some cases, at least one of the remote child job exits, but the local PS session state reports the jobs as `"Running"` and the session hangs waiting for the job to finish.

Is this a known bug in PSv2? Is there a workaround or technique to allow PS to correctly detect when a remote child job exits?

Comment: Do you have any code to show what objects, or properties you are looking at? Have you tried to look at the *session's* *runspace*? [System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace] AvailabilityChanged event?

Comment: How do you determine that the child job exited?

Answer (score 1):

How about:  `Remove-PSSession`

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session (Get-PSSession)
$s = Get-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session $s
```

OR

```
$r = Get-PSSession -ComputerName Serv*
$r | Remove-PSSession
```

[Powershell Core: Remove-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Invoke-Command -Session I believe you will need to use the Get-PSSession command to get the updated status. From [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx/):

-Session

*Runs the command in the specified Windows PowerShell sessions (PSSessions). Enter a variable that contains the PSSessions or a command that creates or gets the PSSessions, such as a New-PSSession or Get-PSSession command.*